# Adobe AIR HTML+JavaScript app vs. hardware acceleration

Tags: html, air, hardware-acceleration, webkit-transform

I'm developing an HTML application for mobiles and desktops. The application is optimized for WebKit based environment. To improve a rendering speed I'm using hardware accelerated layers (something like `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` etc...).

This works great on my iOS devices (using PhoneGap aka Cordova to package a "native" app).

On Windows and OS X I'm using Adobe AIR 3.5 to package a captive runtime HTML/JavaScript based application. I have found this to be the best solution (for now) even though I have tried many others (Cordova for Windows 7 / OS X, TideSDK, ...).

The point is that the HTML rendering in Adobe AIR seems not to be hardware accelerated. Does anyone of you have experience with this? Is here any possibility to enable hardware accelerated layers in AIR HTML rendering?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As far as I know, Air only has acceleration available if you use the Stage3D library of ActionScript.

Comment: Air has hardware acceleration. They even improved it last year.

http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2012/02/mobile-gaming-gets-a-performance-boost-adobe-air-3-2-with-2d-and-3d-hardware-acceleration-announced/

Comment: Actually I've been developing flash/AIR Actionscript apps for a long time and I know quite a lot about hardware acceleration. The thing is that I need to bundle HTML based app not SWF. So the my question is whether it's possible to enable webkits hardware acceleration - or at least I hope that AIR uses webkit for HTML rendering :)

Comment: Adobe AIR generally hasn't innovated on the HTML/webkit side since they focused on iOS, so all the GPU / hardware acceleration is all for Flash / mobile. Take a look at node-webkit instead.